# Can I force Jersey framework to scan only one package while creating WADL?

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, jersey

I have a project where I have kept web service in two separate package. One package contain customer face web services and another contains in house usage web services. I want jersey to only scan the customer facing package and generate  WADL.

Comment: I asked this question on the mailing list and got no answer.  I do not believe it is possible.  I tried having two distinct servlets in my web.xml and it did not help either.  I am curious if you will get a response.

Comment: Yes I tried that too but no luck

Answer (score 0):

In general I was not able to find any way to split wadl generation logic by configuration. But here is hack you can perform. There is class called GenerateWadlTask.java This basically does the wadl generation logic for jersey. You can just extend this class in your custom application wadl generation task and use it as per your logic. For code example just download the jersey server source jar and look at the class. The logic is pretty straight forward.

hope this help.

**EDIT:- There is a maven plugin called enunicate http://enunciate.codehaus.org/
That will make your life easy.**